# upload different type files using codeigniter 3?

Tags: php, codeigniter, file-upload

Is it possible to upload different files type using two input files? I created a form upload with two input and now I'm confused why the file name is same even when i uploaded different files with different name?

this is my controller :

```
public function file_data() {

    $data['program'] = $this->input->post('program');
    $this->load->library('upload');

    $config['upload_path'] = './uploaded_files/laporan/absen';
    $config['allowed_types'] = 'pdf';

    $this->upload->initialize($config);
    if (!$this->upload->do_upload('file_absen')) {
        $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
        $this->load->view('tutor/upload_form', $error);

    } else {
        unset($config);
        $config['upload_path'] = './uploaded_files/laporan/nilai';
        $config['allowed_types'] = 'xls|xlsx';
        $config['overwrite'] = FALSE;
        //$config['max_size'] = '15000';
        $this->upload->initialize($config);
        if (!$this->upload->do_upload('file_nilai')) {
            $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
            $this->load->view('tutor/upload_form', $error); 
        } else {
            $upload_data = $this->upload->data();

            //get the uploaded file name
            $data['file_absen'] = $upload_data['file_name'];
            $data['file_nilai'] = $upload_data['file_name'];

            //store pic data to the db
            $this->laporan_model->simpan_data($data);
            redirect(base_url() . "tutor/laporan_np");
        }
    }
}
```

this is my model :

```
//fetch all data from db
function ambil_data(){
    $all_files = $this->db->get('laporan');
    return $files_pics->result();
}

//save datadata to db
function simpan_data($data){
    $insert_data['program']    = $data['program'];  
    $insert_data['file_nilai'] = $data['file_nilai'];
    $insert_data['file_absen'] = $data['file_absen'];       


    $query = $this->db->insert('laporan', $insert_data);
}
```

```html
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="file_nilai">File Nilai*:</label>
    <input type="file" name="file_nilai" class="form-control"  id="file_nilai">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="file_absen">File Absen*:</label>
    <input type="file" name="file_absen" class="form-control"  id="file_absen">
  </div>
```

Comment: could you post your $upload_data array? echo '<pre>'; print_r($upload_data); echo '</pre>';

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just rewrite your conditional to :

```
public function file_data() {

    $data['program'] = $this->input->post('program');
    $this->load->library('upload');

    $config['upload_path'] = './uploaded_files/laporan/absen';
    $config['allowed_types'] = 'pdf';

    $this->upload->initialize($config);
    if (!$this->upload->do_upload('file_absen')) {
        $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
        $this->load->view('tutor/upload_form', $error);

    } else {
        $upload_data_absen = $this->upload->data(); // added this..
        unset($config);
        $config['upload_path'] = './uploaded_files/laporan/nilai';
        $config['allowed_types'] = 'xls|xlsx';
        $config['overwrite'] = FALSE;
        //$config['max_size'] = '15000';
        $this->upload->initialize($config);
        if (!$this->upload->do_upload('file_nilai')) {
            $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
            $this->load->view('tutor/upload_form', $error); 
        } else {
            $upload_data_nilai = $this->upload->data(); // changed this..

            //get the uploaded file name
            $data['file_absen'] = $upload_data_absen['file_name']; // changed this..
            $data['file_nilai'] = $upload_data_nilai['file_name']; // changed this..

            //store pic data to the db
            $this->laporan_model->simpan_data($data);
            redirect(base_url() . "tutor/laporan_np");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I never thought to change name $upload_data to each condition .. thank you very mush @Hasta Dhana..this is works for me :)